# Concepts about solving systems of differential equations by elimination

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let's say that I have these equations:

$dx/dt = 2x - y$

$dy/dt = x$

Then I derivate the first one and take the negative of the second one. I add them both and get:

$(D^2 - 2D + 1)x = 0$

Where $D$ is $d/dt$. I know how to solve these, long story short the answer is $c1e^t + c2te^t$. I also know that in order to solve the system by elimination I need an $x$ general solution and a $y$ general solution, so:

1. The answer I got, Is it the $x$ one or the $y$ one? My guess is that it's the $x$ one, since the thing I was differentiating was $x$. Does it even matter which one is $x$ and which one $y$?
2. In every example I've seen the $x$ solution and the $y$ solution are the same. For example, I could say that the other solution is $c3e^t + c4te^t$, Is this always true? I guess there could be cases when it isn't, so I don't wanna risk making assumptions.
3. If there are cases when both solutions are different, This means that I have to make it all from the beginning but this time cancel the $x$ terms instead of the $y$ terms right?

Comment: Please use Mathjax to express your computations symbolically, e.g. `$x$` produces "$x$".

Comment: @Moo Thanks, my bad.

Comment: @AylaMao Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: 1. The $x$ One. 2. No, if the system is not linear you can find other types of solutions. If the system is linear every solution can be expressed as a combination of eigenfunctions, so they will all look the same. 3. No. You just need to subsitute the solution you found in one of the equations to find a first order DE which you can solve in the usual way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have:
$x = C_1 e^t + C_2 te^t$
Now plug these into the original equations to find y.

$\frac{dy}{dt} = C_1 e^t + C_2 te^t$

$y = \int c_1 e^t + c_2 te^t dt = (C_1-C_2) e^t + C_2 t e^t$

If you have initial conditions, you can now solve for them.  If not, you are done.